# Convert EXP number to real number

Tags: excel

I get following number in Excel and I have to convert it to a real number. How can I do that?

I get
+24.21E+00 or +2.8954E+03

I need
24,21 or 2895,4

Thank you very much!

**SOLUTION in German** (Change point seperator to comma and to decimal number)

=WERT(ERSETZEN(O73;FINDEN(".";O73);1;","))

Comment: nitpicky: those are already "real" numbers

Comment: You are right, I will change the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a value is in A1 then use: =NUMBERVALUE(A1)

Note: If your locale uses , for the decimal point but the string you have uses . then do =NUMBERVALUE(A1;".")

For Excel 2010:

=VALUE(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",")))

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately I use Office 2010

Comment: In that case, this works for me:

=VALUE(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",")))

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Format Cells** Dialog:

[image]

From the Menu Bar.

Comment: Thats good, thank you. Now I just have to handle the comma / point separator